# How can I simultaneously use multiple IM sessions

Tags: instant-messaging, google-talk, yahoo-messenger

Is there a tool which will allow me to use all my IM identities from Yahoo | Google at the same time. I would prefer not to logout and login with a different IM identity if I have to communicate with a different set of users. Meebo doesn't allow me to do this either.

Comment: Meebo doesn't allow you to sign on to multiple instances of Gtalk and Yahoo?  It's always worked for me... you just have to sign up to be a Meebo user, which as far as I know is still free.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at  [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're looking for a Windows/PC client.

Try [Digsby](http://digsby.com).

Comment: am looking for a PC client only

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) (my personal favorite) and [Digsby](http://digsby.com/), there is [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/), which I believe was one of the original few programs that allowed this.

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin as mentioned - great for windows

Adium - good for OS X

Meebo - online.

I know meebo allows multiple google accounts since I use it, yahoo should also work but I don't use multiple yahoo accts personally.
There were other multi-protocol clients before too that did this like Miranda, Trillian, etc. the keyword here is "multi-protocol" im client.